# REST api to upload multiple notes and attachments at once

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api, images

I am working on an app that allows customers to upload images, video, (even gif) into my app. Once the case is processed on my app, I want to place those media files into Salesforce. I have a case record that I would this attached to.

I see multiple records can be added in Rest [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm), and that files can be added to notes and attachments. Can I upload multiple notes and attachments in a single rest call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are a few ways to upload files. You can use the API you referenced in your question (the "[create new records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm)" API), and you can also upload using a multipart upload.

For the first type of upload, the file is uploaded as a base64-encoded data. It would look like this:

```
POST /services/data/v43.0/composite/tree/Attachment
Content-Type: application/json

{ "records": 
  [ { "attributes": { "type": "Attachment", "referenceId": "rec1" },
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "name": "hello-world.txt",
    "body": "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=",
    "parentId": "001100000123456" 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

This method is limited to about 37MB uploads, however, because this API call is limited to 50MB, and Base64-encoding increases a file's size by 33% during transfer.

Alternatively, you can use the [composite multipart API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) to deal with larger files.

```
POST /services/data/v42.0/composite/sobjects/
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="boundary_string"

--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="collection"
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "allOrNone" : false,
    "records" :
    [
        {
            "attributes" :
            {
                "type" : "Attachment",
                "binaryPartName": "binaryPart1",
                "binaryPartNameAlias": "Body"
            },
            "Description" : "Marketing Brochure",
            "ParentId" : "some-parent-id",
            "Name" : "Brochure",
            "ContentType" : "pdf"
        },
        {
            "attributes" :
            {
                "type" : "Attachment",
                "binaryPartName": "binaryPart2",
                "binaryPartNameAlias": "Body"
            },
            "Description" : "Pricing Overview",
            "ParentId" : "some-record-id",
            "Name" : "Pricing",
            "ContentType" : "pdf"
        }
    ]
}

--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binaryPart1"; filename="Brochure.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

Binary data goes here.

--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binaryPart2"; filename="Pricing.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

Binary data goes here.

--boundary_string--
```

**NOTE**: This is just a slightly modified version of what's in the documentation. Feel free to read the documentation for any further questions.